# How to get div height after the action slider down or slider up?

Tags: jquery, height

Code in here: [jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T6HnW/1/)

I wanna to get the `div#content` height when it finish the action of `slider down/up`.

For example, in demo, I type some words, they make the div height is `36px`, so if I click `slider down`, I need get the value `36`, and if I click `slider up`, I need return the value `0`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then, but it in the callback function of the `slideDown` or `slideUp`, for example like:

```
 $('#content').slideDown('slow', function(){
        var height = $(this).height();
  });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T6HnW/3/)

**Notice that** it will give you the same height 38 in the two cases the `slideDown` and the `slideUp`, becouse the two functions *don't change the height property of the `div`*, but only the *`display` proprty* from `none` to `block`, so the div `#content`'s height property is the same after slideing down as it's height before.

Comment: hey, thanks for a help, but `slideup` not work, the value should be zero, but now still `36`

Comment: @Giberno, It is working in the example page I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old thread, but it came up first when I searched for this so I assume others will land here as well.

Using the callback is what I do if I need the value after the animation completes, but in my use case, I needed the height before the animation so I could expand another element to the same height.  For this, I did the following:

```
//Get height (start and end)
var startHeight = $el.height();
$el.show();
var endHeight = $el.height();
$el.hide();

/**Do something useful with the height here**/
$el2.animate({height: endHeight});

//Slide the element down
$el.slideDown();
```

Because JavaScript is single threaded, the show/hide is never rendered.